# Number of Search Results from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Given a column of strings I would like to find the number of search results from a website (e.g. sciencedirect.com) for each string. An existing answer [Number of Google Results from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763140/number-of-google-results-from-excel) works well for Google.

Unfortunately this solution creates the search URL from the string i.e. a Google search for *example* contains the word *example*. The sites I want to use do not do this.

A search for *example* returns the URL http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleListURL&_method=list&_ArticleListID=1860967815&_sort=r&_st=13&view=c&_acct=C000053194&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=1495569&md5=0ef30742e917da15236ef1824058a1db&searchtype=a

Any idea how I achived the same result with this type of search engine.

Comment: Couldn't you get this information from the API instead of scraping? http://www.developer.sciverse.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to examine the form you submit when you click on the Search button. The form sends a GET request which containes the search terms, but then you get redirected to the result list page, and the URL of the results page does not contain the search terms any more.

I have successfully searched for "corpus" with this URL:

```
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=QuickSearchURL&_method=submitForm&_acct=C000228598&_origin=home&_zone=qSearch&md5=61ce8901b141d527683913a240486ac4&qs_all=corpus
```

Note that what you'll have to do is

1. download the start page http://www.sciencedirect.com/
2. extract hidden fields from the search form
3. assemble the search URL from the hidden fields
4. add your search term to the search URL in the `qs_all` field
5. send GET request with the search URL
6. follow redirection

Except for `qs_all` all other fields in this URL comes from the the form as hidden fields.
This is the source of the corresponding form, as I downloaded it (before sending the "corpus" search request.):

```
<form name="qkSrch" method="get" target="_top" action="/science" style="margin:0px;">
<input type="hidden" name="_ob" value="QuickSearchURL">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="submitForm">
<input type="hidden" name="_acct" value="C000228598">
<input type="hidden" name="_origin" value="home">
<input type="hidden" name="_zone" value="qSearch">
<input type="hidden" name="md5" value="61ce8901b141d527683913a240486ac4">

<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0;">
<tbody><tr valign="middle">

<!-- Code related for toggling labels -->

   <td align="right"><label for="qs_all" id="fieldLabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;All fields</label></td>
   <td align="left"><input class="textbox qsinput xpstyle" type="text" name="qs_all" id="qs_all" value="" size="30" maxlength="450" title="For example: heart attack AND behavior?" tabindex="1"></td>



   <td align="right"><label for="qs_author">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Author</label></td>
   <td align="left" colspan="5"><input class="textbox qsinput xpstyle" type="text" name="qs_author" id="qs_author" value="" size="33" maxlength="450" title="e.g. J S Smith or John Smith or Smith JS" tabindex="2" style="_width:100%"></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap">

   </td><td></td><td></td>
   <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" width="90%" valign="middle">
   <a href="/science?_ob=MiamiSearchURL&amp;_method=requestForm&amp;_btn=Y&amp;_acct=C000228598&amp;_version=1&amp;_urlVersion=1&amp;_userid=10&amp;md5=18a1082f74248d90d465ee65804fd7db" style="vertical-align:bottom;font-size:0.92em;">Advanced search</a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>

   <td align="right"><label for="qs_title">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Journal/Book&nbsp;title</label></td>
   <td align="left"><input class="textbox qsinput xpstyle" type="text" id="qs_title" name="qs_title" value="" size="30" maxlength="450" title="For example: journal of molecular biology" tabindex="3"></td>

   <td align="right" class="toggleQukSrch2"><label for="qs_vol" id="volField">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Volume</label></td>
   <td align="left" class="toggleQukSrch"><input class="textbox qsinput xpstyle" type="text" name="qs_vol" id="qs_vol" value="" size="3" maxlength="10" style="width:30px;" tabindex="4"></td>
   <td align="right" class="toggleQukSrch2"><label for="qs_issue" id="issueField">&nbsp;&nbsp;Issue</label></td>
   <td align="left" class="toggleQukSrch"><input class="textbox qsinput xpstyle" type="text" name="qs_issue" id="qs_issue" value="" size="3" maxlength="10" style="width:30px" tabindex="5"></td>
   <td align="right" class="toggleQukSrch2"><label for="qs_pages" id="pageField">&nbsp;&nbsp;Page</label></td>
   <td align="right" class="toggleQukSrch"><input class="textbox qsinput xpstyle" type="text" name="qs_pages" id="qs_pages" value="" size="3" maxlength="10" title="For example: 14-27" style="width:30px" tabindex="6"></td>

   <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
   <input class="button" id="submit_search" type="Submit" alt="Submit Quick Search" title="Submit Quick Search" value="Search ScienceDirect" tabindex="8" name="sdSearch">
   </td> 



 <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" colspan="8" valign="bottom">
      <a class="icon_qmarkHelpsci_dir" href="/science?_ob=HelpURL&amp;_file=qs_tips.htm&amp;_acct=C000228598&amp;_version=1&amp;_urlVersion=0&amp;_userid=10&amp;md5=2bd779305b31602341744eaa786e2f0a" target="sdhelp" onmouseover="window.status='Help is Available';return true" onmouseout="window.status='';return true" onclick="var helpWin;helpWin=window.open('/science?_ob=HelpURL&amp;_file=qs_tips.htm&amp;_acct=C000228598&amp;_version=1&amp;_urlVersion=0&amp;_userid=10&amp;md5=2bd779305b31602341744eaa786e2f0a','sdhelp','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,directories=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,width=760,height=570');helpWin.focus();return false" tabindex="9" style="font-size:0.92em;padding-right:0;">Search tips</a>
   </td>
   </tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

**EDIT** 
Continued with How to extract the number of results from the results page.

Your assumption is right, you'll have to change other parts of the code, namely that extracts the number of results value.

Let's stick with the previous example. 
When searching from "corpus", you will find this line in the source of the result page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TOTAL_PAGES" value="2836">
```

And you'll want to extract 2836. Hence you will search for something like `<input type="hidden" name="TOTAL_PAGES" value="` and get the subequent value before the closing quote.

I am not going to tell you how to code in VBA, but it is basic String manipulation so I hope you can handle it.

Comment: Thanks I am having difficulty adapting the code to the new website, I don't fully understand what the "Number of Google Results from Excel" code is doing. I have changed the search_url but I assume that other parts of the code require changing

Comment: Edited the answer, elaborated on this one

Comment: When I view the source of the results page I cannot find the <input type="hidden" name="TOTAL_PAGES" value="2836"> from where and how are you extracting this?

Comment: Sorry I have now found it, but I have noticed that Total_Pages is the number of pages not the number of results (i.e. a much smaller number)

Comment: You are very clever indeed! The number of TOTAL_PAGES is not the number of all the search-results. Now, how do you think you can figure the number of result out of the number of pages? (Hint: check the page size, i.e. the number of results per page. I guess it'll be 50.) (Spoiler alert: multiply page_size with TOTAL_PAGES, in this case 50*2836=141800)

Comment: One final problem, I am modifying the code to use the advanced search, the advanced search has drop down lists which have different formatting, what should I add to the URL to use drop down lists currently I have
 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=MiamiSearchURL&_method=submitForm&_acct=C000053194&_temp=all_search.tmpl&md5=9e299e9289462d7805ab0a5dcc9cff5c&test_alid=&keywordOpt=TITLE-ABSTR-KEY&Subscribed=0&SearchText=test 
which returns the error select a source [from the drop down list]