# How to get Google search results in Excel for a certain word

Tags: excel, search-engine, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of Google Results from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763140/number-of-google-results-from-excel)

I have the following situation, I would like to gather the number of search results for a certain word in Excel. I will explain it better with an example:

I have several words in an Excel file as follows:

Name----------------------------Results in Google

Shoes

Shirt

Book

Mobile

...

And I would like to obtain the following

Name----------------------------Results in Google

Shoes  123.234 results aprox

Shirt  53.334 results aprox

Book  243.234 results aprox

Mobile  1.234 results aprox

...

I'm not sure how to gather the result for any particular words (with "" too) in Excel using google.

Any suggestion?

Best regards

Comment: Here is the solution, thanks in any case :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763140/number-of-google-results-from-excel